# Why is my pandas dataframe not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I create a data frame as follows (I am using PyCharm and Python 3.6):

```
import pandas as pd

data1=pd.read_csv('LoanDataReport_jan_thru_may.txt', sep='|',
                  low_memory=False)

data2=pd.read_csv('LoanDataReport_jun_thru_sep.txt', sep='|',
                  low_memory=False)

data3=pd.read_csv('LoanDataReport_oct_thru_dec.txt', sep='|',
                  low_memory=False)

datafinal=pd.concat([data1,data2,data3])

print(datafinal)
```

This runs as expected and displays a portion of datafinal.

THEN, I comment out the lines of code I just ran using # and add a new line of code to get the dtypes.  It looks like this:

```
#import pandas as pd
#
#data1=pd.read_csv('LoanDataReport_jan_thru_may.txt', sep='|',
#                  low_memory=False)
#
#data2=pd.read_csv('LoanDataReport_jun_thru_sep.txt', sep='|',
#                  low_memory=False)
#
#data3=pd.read_csv('LoanDataReport_oct_thru_dec.txt', sep='|',
#                  low_memory=False)
#
#datafinal=pd.concat([data1,data2,data3])
#
#print(datafinal)
#

print(datafinal.dtypes)
```

I get the following error:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 "/Users/myname/Desktop/Python3/Import Data.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Python3/Import Data.py", line 17, in 
    print(datafinal.dtypes)
NameError: name 'datafinal' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

WHY DOES THIS OCCUR?  WHY AM I NOT ABLE TO CONTINUE WORKING ON datafinal WITHOUT RUNNING THE ENTIRE CODE EVERYTIME?  ALL HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to read about [variables and scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) in Python.

You have a standalone script where you define a global variable `datafinal`. That variable is visible only during a script lifetime and it's not preserved between your first and second attempts. When you run your script a second time, after you have commented all but the last statement, you are trying to access a varible that does not exist.

If you would like to explore your data in a gradual manner, look at the [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/). One way to get it is to use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) Python distribution.

Comment: Thank you.  I am very new to Python. So i believe I have anaconda and jupiter installed.  In my terminal did pip install --upgrade pip and got he response  "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages".  I then did pip install jupyter and go the message "Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages".  I am still having the same issue as before.  Do I need to do something else now that I have those applications?  Do I still use PyCharm to run my Python code?

Comment: What same issue as before? NameError: name 'datafinal' is not defined? It has nothing to do with Jupyter, just don't comment ```datafinal=pd.concat([data1,data2,data3])``` in your code before you are trying to print it. Have you read "Variables and Scope" article?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I installed Jupyter and spent some time understanding it....it is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you are happy with the solution.

Comment: i did upvote but since I am new it says my vote won't count on public viewing.  not sure how/where i "accept" the answer

Comment: There should be a checkmark next to the answer, under the voting buttons (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).